# How to adjust the evaluation function for various difficulties in chess?

Tags: java, chess, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I am curious what adjustments I can make to my evaluation function in a chess game for different difficulties. Assuming the player is an average player, if I were to have say, easy, medium and hard, what would I evaluate? Currently I am just checking material, piece-square tables and mobility and I cannot beat it. Are there some aspects of an evaluation function(I am talking about the Basic Evaluation Features on this page: https://www.chessprogramming.org/Evaluation) that are essential to keep and some that I can implement that will have a more of an effect than others.

My search algorithm (minimax with alpha-beta):

```
public int miniMaxAlphaBeta(int depth, boolean maximisingPlayer, int alpha, int beta) {
    if(maximisingPlayer) {
        if(depth == 0) return evaluate();
        int best = -9999;
        m: for(Piece piece : getWhitePieces()) for(Move move : piece.getMoves()) {
            movePiece(piece, move.x, move.y);
            if(piece.isFriendlyKingInCheck()) { undoMove(); continue; }
            int score = miniMaxAlphaBeta(depth-1, !maximisingPlayer, alpha, beta);
            undoMove();
            if(score > best) {
                best = score;
                //here I'll record the piece and move to make
            }
            alpha = Math.max(alpha, best);
            if(beta<=alpha) break m;
        }
        return best;
    } else {
        if(depth == 0) return -evaluate();
        int best = 9999;
        m: for(Piece piece : getBlackPieces()) for(Move move : piece.getMoves()) {
            MovePiece(piece, move.x, (move.y);
            if(piece.isFriendlyKingInCheck) { undoMove(); continue; }
            int score = miniMaxAlphaBeta(depth-1, !maximisingPlayer, alpha, beta);
            undoMove();
            if(score < best) {
                best = score;
                //here I'll record the piece and move to make
            }
            beta = Math.min(beta, best);
            if(beta<=alpha) break m;
        }
        return best;
    }
}
```

My evaluation function:

```
public int evaluate() {
    int whiteMaterial = 0;
    int blackMaterial = 0;
    int positionalValue = 0;
    int mobility = 0;
    for(Piece piece : getAllPieces()) {
        if (piece.isBlackPiece()) blackMaterial += getPieceValue(piece); //returns relative piece value of piece
        else if (p.isWhitePiece()) whiteMaterial += getPieceValue(piece);
        positionalValue += getPieceSquareTableValue(piece); //adds whichever value it is on it's piece-square table at it's current position
        mobility += getMobility(piece); //adds 15 for every move this piece can make
    }
    return (whiteMaterial-blackMaterial) + positionalValue + mobility;
}
```

Comment: It's probably easier to make to program more "stupid" by limiting search depth (search time) than to actually code "didn't see that move" into the evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Hard - use everything you've got:
- search for the max depth
- count pieces
- count mobility
- count king's safety
- count controlling center of the board
- use quiescence search, check extention

Medium and Easy - properly lower serach depth and skip some of the mentioned features.